# Providing password review results to auditors

Tags: passwords, hash, audit

The IT Security department is getting audited and the auditor had approached our IT Security team and requests to see results of the password review process, which compares existing database of passwords which are hashed and custom salt against the password policy requirements. If I am not wrong, I should not be providing them these results. Am I correct?

Comment: Results? Yes. Passwords? No.

Answer (score 5):

> The auditor requested the results of the password review process.

This seems a perfectly reasonable request. The result of the password review process is not a list of all passwords, but rather the information that you have gathered from the process. It could look something like this:

> During the password review process, 1292 passwords were audited. 1171 of those passwords were personal passwords, and 121 passwords were for service accounts.
>
> Out of 1171 personal passwords
>
> - 58 passwords were found on publicly available leaks
> - 25 passwords could be cracked within 24 hours
> - additional 7 passwords could be cracked within a week
>
> The remaining 1081 passwords (~92.31%) could not be cracked within one week using a cloud computing platform.
>
> *[... more stuff goes here ...]*
>
> In order to improve the situation, measures will be taken to compare user passwords to known leaked passwords and reject the password in this situation.

This way, the auditor can be reasonably certain that you actually conducted a password review process. For a more in-depth audit, the auditor may want to see more documents regarding the process, such as your requirements for a secure password, how the cracking was conducted, etc.

However, no serious auditor would **ever** require to see plaintext passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Reasonable auditors should want to avoid being exposed to the actual raw cracked passwords, and just request reasonable evidence that the audits are being conducted properly and thoroughly.

You can provide summary reports, along with *redacted* samples of the results, without exposing individual passwords.

Answer (score 1):

1. The question

If I understand well, auditors are requesting the results of the password review process. That is the report, or presentation, or whatever else, describing how the review was performed, a summary of the deviations, and the status of the corrective actions. In a mature IT team, such a documentation is readily available. The request appears reasonable. The question is whether to provide or not the documentation.

2. How to address the decision to deliver or not the documentation

Before answering the request from the auditors, I suggest clarifying three points. The first thing is to determine the context of the request. Is it part of a service requested by (senior) management or directors? That is, do they really need this documentation to meet their agreed audit objectives? if yes, the request is legit. Please note that they specific audit objectives might not be shared with your team. Secondly, is the request coming from the proper auditors? You might need to confirm directly and independently with the audit team leader. Thirdly, are you personally qualified to share the "report"? Depending on the organization, a single point of contact is determined in advance. The single point of contact should be involved.

To sum up, if the request is legit, the auditors can have access to results of the password review. Your policies and procedures may set out how the results must be provided, including who should provide the requested documentation. If it is not you, please ensure that your share your concern with your management. Someone should take care of their request. Auditors may be prone to escalate.

3. Miscellaneous

I understand that the auditors have not requested the raw data. However, please note that auditors may request access to raw data, except plain text passwords of course, in a secure environment to re-perform the review. Reperformance is a common audit step. Auditors may also request to observe a password review exercise. Observation is also a common audit step. In many organizations, policies and procedures set the requirements to allow auditors accessing data. If these criteria are really met, you might not be in a position to reject the request from auditors. Finally, expect follow-up questions, including requests to be talked through the report.